# Creating a new planner in OMPL using Python

Tags: moveit, motion-planning, path-planning, ompl

I am using OMPL in order to create a new planner using OMPL. The documentation gives only a short description of how to do so:

```
[1]Publicly derive the new class from ompl::base::Planner
[2]Provide an implementation of the method solve() from ompl::base::Planner
```

I was wondering if these instructions can be extended to python as so far i have not been able to find anything on that.